# Allowed mappings in BigQueryColumnCheckOperator

Tags: airflow

I have a question related to bigquery Operators from airflow-
Maybe it's a newbie question, but here it goes.
Im trying to use the BigQueryColumnCheckOperator and one of it's parameters are "column_mappings"
But I can't find what kind of mappings are allowed in it, in the documentation as far as I search I didn't find them. I only Just know the mapping shown in the example below.

```
column_check = BigQueryColumnCheckOperator(
        task_id="column_check",
        table=f"{DATASET}.{TABLE_1}",
        column_mapping={"value": {"null_check": {"equal_to": 0}}},
    )
```

Maybe there's some BigQuery Oficial documentation where I can find the answer but I couldn't find it.
thank you very much in advance

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryColumnCheckOperator

Comment: @dfundako I already read that documentation, but I can't find specified what kind of mappings you can do.
in the example above it says "column_mapping={"value": {"null_check": {"equal_to": 0}}}" right? 
but how many other can I do? am I allowed to do somehting like :
column_mapping={"value": {"duplicates": {"equal_to": 0}}} I don't know if i'm explaining it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BigQueryColumnCheckOperator` inherits from the `SQLColumnCheckOperator`, and you can find a list of supported `column_mapping`s for all Operators that inherit from `SQLColumnCheckOperator` in its [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.5.0/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py#L340-L346).

As of `apache-airflow-providers-common-sql` version 1.3.2, these checks include:

```
column_checks = {
        "null_check": "SUM(CASE WHEN {column} IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)",
        "distinct_check": "COUNT(DISTINCT({column}))",
        "unique_check": "COUNT({column}) - COUNT(DISTINCT({column}))",
        "min": "MIN({column})",
        "max": "MAX({column})",

}
```

You can learn more about implementing data quality operators in [Astronomer's guide on data quality checks using SQL Operators](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-sql-data-quality#example-sqlcolumncheckoperator).

Disclaimer: I currently work at Astronomer.

Comment: Thx, i really aprecciate your answer , Can I ask you another question, if not bother you  How do you pull the results from the BigQueryColumnCheckOperator, even if it's fails the checks?  I only find the JobId in the xcoms, and the results are shown in logs.

Comment: The way the operator is currently written does not allow for additional XCom information to be written, because the [`execute` method doesn't return anything](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.5.0/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py#L406), which is how the `do_xcom_push` parameter works. You can open a PR to return the `column_mapping` from `execute`, but that wouldn't solve the failure case.

Comment: @RNHTTR why is this feature depended on Airflow 2.5.0? This seems to be provider code